# c++ Log class inefficient?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote a *very* simple Log class for a game im writing just to see some info in the terminal. But the way i did it bugs me because i feel its too inefficient. Every time i log something its constructor and destructor are called. So if i want to print the current frame rate (ex 60fps) the cont/desct are called 60 times a sec (creating and destroying 60 log objects a second). i dont want to keep passing a log object around the game every time i want to log something and i dont want to use signletons. is there a better solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


class Log
{
public:
    Log() : os()
    {

    }

    ~Log()
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", os.str().c_str());
    }

    std::ostringstream &Write()
    {
        os << "from log class: " << 1337 << "\t";

        return os;
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream os;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Log().Write() << "Hello world " << 45;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know about static classes?

Comment: @AndreasHenning there are no static classes in C++.

Comment: But there are static methods.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes a class with only static members can surely be considered a static class. actually, that's even the definition of static classes, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: There are also non-member functions in C++. If you want some form of scoping for their names, C++ also has a feature for that. It's called "namespaces".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to go with some existing logging framework. People put a lot of efforts to make it as fast and as flexible as possible.

Here is good description of existing logging frameworks:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assumption that the constructor and destructor are inefficient.  In my experience if they are declared in a header file (as yours are) and if they are simple (as yours are) then you can trust the compiler to inline them and do a very good job.  The call to printf is going to dominate the time.

Comment: Yes, but you still can't ignore the time spent allocating the memory as well as the stuff the runtime does behind your back when creating an instance, especially when you can easily avoid it.